# What is the difference between these two Verilog codes?

Tags: verilog

I have seen two code styles about dealing with a flag signal or control signal. Some FPGAers like the following code style.

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   if(rst) begin
      flag <= 0;
   end
   else begin
      flag <= 0;
      if(****) begin
         flag <= 1;
      end 
      else if(***) begin
          ***;
      end
      else begin
         ***;
      end
   end
end
```

The other style is shown as follows:

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
   if(rst) begin
      flag <= 0;
   end
   else begin
      if(***) begin
         flag <= 1;
      end
      else if(***) begin
         flag <= 0;
      end
      else begin
         flag <= 0;
      end
   end
end
```

I want to know the impact on the whole IC chip design procedure when I code the two different styles at the RTL design stage.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question and very opinionated. If you have many variables do deal with in one always block, the first style might be preferable. But the second style is explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd style is preferable.

In the 1st style, you have multiple nonblocking assignments potentially active at the same clock edge.  There is no need for that.  Your linting tool may generate warnings about it.

The 2nd style is much easier to understand because you explicitly make one nonblocking assignment per branch.  There is no ambiguity.